# What part of the kernel is open sourced?

Tags: kernel, open-source

Where exactly is the "large swath of the code base" that Stephen Wolfram said was open sourced?

Comment: Where did he say that any of it was, out of interest? I hope he wasn't referring to the bits they repackaged, like GMP and Tesseract…

Comment: Google returns no such quote. What is the source of your quote?

Comment: Where did he say that any part of the kernel was open sourced?  I don't think any of this is open source.

Comment: I saw it in a video, he was talking about WRI's relation with the community, and remarked that this happened once, I'll find it...

Comment: `TextRecognize`. BTW note that there's a difference between open source and free software. SW might have been referring to functions that are or were once written in Mathematica itself so that their implementation could be studied.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Or like [Combintorica](https://www.cs.uiowa.edu/~sriram/Combinatorica/NewCombinatorica.m)

Comment: I don't know specifically what SW was referring to, but there's a decent chunk of code easily viewable inside the Mathematica layout: `SetDirectory[$InstallationDirectory];
FileNames["*.m", {"*"}, Infinity]`

Comment: I think you are confusing "open source" with "open" as in "open to inspection".

Comment: I doubt there was any such reference to the implementation of Mathematica. There is a considerable amount of Mathematica code that is some flavor of openly available. See e.g. demonstrations.wolfram.com; the [licensing](http://www.wolfram.com/legal/terms/wolfram-demonstrations-project.html) will explain the details.